# Comparing the rows of a column in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the below data frame

---

```
df=
 city    code     qty    year
 hyd     1        10    2016
 hyd     2        12    2016
 pune    2        15    2016
 pune    4        25    2016
 hyd     1        10    2017
 hyd     3        12    2017
 pune    1        15    2017
 pune    2        25    2017
 hyd     2        10    2018
 hyd     4        10    2018
 hyd     6        12    2018
 pune    1        15    2018
 pune    4        25    2018
```

I want to add all the unique years as columns here(2016,2017,2018) and compare if same city and code of one year with other years less than the year compared to(i.e. for 2018 compare with 2017,2016,2015 and for 2017 with 2016,2015 and so on..). if same city and code is available in other years then flag it as Y if not present then N. And the the with which we are comparing must be left blank.

The below must be the result data frame.

---

```
city    code     qty    year    year_2016     year_2017    year_2018 
hyd     1         10    2016                                 
hyd     2         12    2016                                         
pune    2         15    2016                                  
pune    4         25    2016                                
hyd     1         10    2017        Y                                          
hyd     3         12    2017        N                         
pune    1         15    2017        N                           
pune    2         25    2017        Y                         
hyd     2         10    2018        Y            N        
hyd     4         12    2018        N            N
hyd     6         12    2018        N            N
pune    1         15    2018        N            Y
pune    4         25    2018        Y            N
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why does `pune, code=2` have the result of `year_2018` as `Y`?

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo. i have edited the df.. thanks

Comment: These results still look inconsistent. The logic in hyd-1 (2017 v 2016) and pune-1 (2018 v 2017) are contradicting.

Comment: leo, i have corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# Get a list of all year, this way we know how many columns to make and which columns to mark as N
all_years = df.year.unique()

def my_func(x):
    # Function to create new year_... rows

    # Get the city and code names
    city, code = x.name

    # This function will return a pandas.DataFrame
    out = pd.DataFrame()

    # Loop through each year
    for key, year in x.iteritems():
        append_series = pd.Series()

        # If this (city, code) has multiple years we must iterate over each year vs the other years
        iterate = [year]
        if len(x.values) > 1:
            iterate = x.drop(key).values

        # Create a pandas.Series to add to the main dataframe 'out'
        for other_year in iterate:
            append_series.at['year'] = year
            append_series.at["year_"+str(other_year)] = "Y"
            append_series.at["city"] = city
            append_series.at["code"] = code

            # If any year does not show up then we must mark is as N
            for missing_year in (set(all_years) - set(x.values)):
                append_series.at["year_" + str(missing_year)] = "N"

        # Add this series to the main dataframe 'out'
        out = out.append(append_series, ignore_index=True)
    return out

df.groupby(['city', 'code'])['year'].apply(my_func).reset_index(drop=True).fillna("")


Out[]:
    city  code    year year_2016 year_2017 year_2018
0    hyd   1.0  2016.0                   Y         N
1    hyd   1.0  2017.0         Y                   N
2    hyd   2.0  2016.0                   N         Y
3    hyd   2.0  2018.0         Y         N          
4    hyd   3.0  2017.0         N         Y         N
5    hyd   4.0  2018.0         N         N         Y
6    hyd   6.0  2018.0         N         N         Y
7   pune   1.0  2017.0         N                   Y
8   pune   1.0  2018.0         N         Y          
9   pune   2.0  2016.0                   Y         N
10  pune   2.0  2017.0         Y                   N
11  pune   4.0  2016.0                   N         Y
12  pune   4.0  2018.0         Y         N
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Dillon. in my case it should only compare it with the years that are less than the year that is compared to(if we are checking for 2016 then year_2016,year_2017,year_2018 must be blank and for 2017 year_2018 must be black). Thanks